# Flutter : Text not order in row widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Code:**

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          model.mp3Files[index].artist,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
        Text(
          model.mp3Files[index].album,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

How to position first text to the left?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Column`

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // add this
  children: [...],
)
```

Comment: If i change localization to the rtl language, it is changed according language direction?@CopsOnRoad

Comment: Yes, it will, because in Flutter, we have `CrossAxisAlignment.start` and not `CrossAxisAlignment.left`.